# Authentication issues with Cloud Endpoints Portal

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-apis-explorer

I have Cloud Endpoints Framework implemented in my App Engine project, and I'd like to migrate from the deprecated API Explorer to the new Endpoints Portal, but I have an authentication issue.

I have one endpoint with authentication enabled with a [Google ID token](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/authentication-method#google_id_token_authentication). But when the user clicks on 'Try This API' in the Endpoints Portal, he is not authenticated. This works with the old API Explorer.
[image]

I use the project described in this tutorial: https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/get-started-frameworks-java.

It has API Management has described in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/adding-api-management) and I followed [these steps](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/authenticating-users#google-id-tokens) to authenticate users

I've added the class below to the sample code to test an API with authentication:

```
package com.example.echo;

import com.google.api.server.spi.auth.common.User;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.Api;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiMethod;
import com.google.api.server.spi.response.UnauthorizedException;

@Api(
        name = "authenticatedApi",
        title = "Authenticated API",
        version = "v1",
        description = "Use OAuth 2.0 to authenticate",
        scopes = {"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"},
        clientIds = {"*"}
)
public class AuthenticatedApi {

    @ApiMethod(name = "sayHello")
    public Message sayHello(User user) throws UnauthorizedException {
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException("Invalid credentials");
        }

        Message message = new Message();
        message.setMessage("Hello " + user.getEmail());
        return message;
    }
}
```

There is a [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/dev-portal-explore-api#configuring_api_explorer_settings) about how configuring the portal for authentication but nothing about OAuth 2.0

I generate and deploy the openapi.json file using the maven plugin and gcloud:

```
$ mvn endpoints-framework:openApiDocs
$ gcloud endpoints services deploy target/openapi-docs/openapi.json
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I checked the doc you [shared](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/dev-portal-explore-api#configuring_api_explorer_settings) and on step Create OAuth client ID I found a link for [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2?hl=en_US). Check it it may be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a current Feature Request for the Google Cloud Endpoints team:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/127623471

Answer (score 0):

So I found a way but I couldn't find any documentation about it.

This [code sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine-java8/endpoints-v2-backend/src/main/java/com/example/echo/Echo.java#L142) suggest that the Cloud Endpoints Portal needs [ESP](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/glossary#extensible_service_proxy). But unlike Cloud Endpoints with OpenApi, [Cloud Endpoints Framework does not use ESP](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/choose-endpoints-option#standard_generation_1_environment_limitations), but:

> a built-in API gateway that provides API management features that are comparable to the features that ESP provides for Endpoints for OpenAPI

Therefore, the openapi.json file generated by `mvn endpoints-framework:openApiDocs` is missing some info.

Here is what I changed:

At the class level, in the @Api annotation:

- added an audience (even though I don't have Android clients and, according to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/decorators-reference#allowed_client_ids_and_audiences), audiences are for Android clients only)
- added a custom authenticator to handle ESP, similar to com.google.api.server.spi.auth.EspAuthenticator

In the openapi.json file, after it's generated with `mvn endpoints-framework:openApiDocs`

- section securityDefinitions, the authorizationUrl https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth (I had an error otherwise)
- in the declaration of the path of my method, the security section with the OAuth scope in it

Sources:

API

```
package com.example.echo;

import com.google.api.server.spi.auth.common.User;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.Api;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiMethod;
import com.google.api.server.spi.response.UnauthorizedException;

@Api(
        name = "authenticatedApi",
        title = "Authenticated API",
        version = "v1",
        description = "Use OAuth to authenticate",
        scopes = {"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"},
        clientIds = {"*"},
        audiences = {"my-web-client-id.apps.googleusercontent.com"},
        authenticators = {CustomAuthenticator.class}
)
public class AuthenticatedApi {

    @ApiMethod(name = "sayHello")
    public Message sayHello(User user) throws UnauthorizedException {
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException("Invalid credentials");
        }

        Message message = new Message();
        message.setMessage("Hello " + user.getEmail());
        return message;
    }
}
```

Anthenticator

```
package com.example.echo;

import com.google.api.auth.UserInfo;
import com.google.api.control.ConfigFilter;
import com.google.api.control.model.MethodRegistry;
import com.google.api.server.spi.auth.EndpointsAuthenticator;
import com.google.api.server.spi.auth.common.User;
import com.google.api.server.spi.response.ServiceUnavailableException;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

public class CustomAuthenticator extends EndpointsAuthenticator {
    private final com.google.api.auth.Authenticator authenticator;

    public CustomAuthenticator() {
        // ESP needs another authenticator
        this.authenticator = com.google.api.auth.Authenticator.create();
    }

    @Override
    public User authenticate(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServiceUnavailableException {
        User user = super.authenticate(request);

        // Testing the user is enough for the API Explorer, not for the Endpoints Portal
        if (user == null) {
            try {
                MethodRegistry.Info methodInfo = ConfigFilter.getMethodInfo(request);
                MethodRegistry.AuthInfo authInfo = methodInfo.getAuthInfo().get();
                String serviceName = ConfigFilter.getService(request).getName();
                UserInfo userInfo = this.authenticator.authenticate(request, authInfo, serviceName);
                user = new User(userInfo.getId(), userInfo.getEmail());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return user;
    }
}
```

openapi.json

```
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "title": "My Application"
  },
  "host": "my-application.appspot.com",
  "basePath": "/_ah/api",
  "schemes": [
    "https"
  ],
  "consumes": [
    "application/json"
  ],
  "produces": [
    "application/json"
  ],
  "paths": {
    "/authenticatedApi/v1/sayHello": {
      "post": {
        "operationId": "AuthenticatedApiSayHello",
        "parameters": [],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "A successful response",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/Message"
            }
          }
        },
        "security": [
          {
            "google_id_token_https": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"]
          }
        ],
        "x-security": [
          {
            "google_id_token_https": {
              "audiences": [
                "my-web-client-id.apps.googleusercontent.com"
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "securityDefinitions": {
    "google_id_token_https": {
      "type": "oauth2",
      "authorizationUrl": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth",
      "flow": "implicit",
      "x-google-issuer": "https://accounts.google.com",
      "x-google-jwks_uri": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs"
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "Email": {
      "properties": {
        "email": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    },
    "Message": {
      "properties": {
        "message": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```